# Where do I find my oneget Windows Package Management installed apps?

Tags: powershell, windows-packagemanagement

I just installed the newest windows 10 ctp and wanted to try oneget to install everything I need.
When using for example `find-package vlc | install-package -verbose -force` it gives me the following output:

```
VERBOSE: NuGet: Installing 'vlc 2.1.5.20140811'.
VERBOSE: NuGet: Successfully installed 'vlc 2.1.5.20140811'.

Name                                     Version      Status       ProviderName     Source           Summary
----                                     -------      ------       ------------     ------           -------
vlc                                      2.1.5.201... Installed    Chocolatey       chocolatey       VLC Media Player
```

although it tells me it installed vlc, I can't find it on my system. Neither is there a new folder in `C:\Program Files\` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\` nor can the start menu search find it nor can i start vlc from powershell.

Where do I find my oneget-installed apps?

**Edit (other possible solution):** If you run into this problem and can't even find your applications in the directory you'll get by following mikemaccana's solution, then you've probably got the same problem I've had:
*You need to set the execution policy to at least remotesigned by running `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` as admin!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the package provider. If Package Management installs a package from Chocolatey, the install dir is `C:\Chocolatey`

```
$ Get-Package openssh | select ProviderName

ProviderName
------------
Chocolatey
```

And then:

```
 $ ls C:\Chocolatey\lib\


    Directory: C:\Chocolatey\lib


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       24/10/2016  11:55 AM                openssh.0.0.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found the answer. OneGet might have the requirement that script execution is set to remotesigned at least. So, after doing `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`, oneget finally works!

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question 'Where does oneget install packages to?'

Comment: Does "finally works" mean that OneGet (currently PackageManagement) installs packages to "Program Files", when the execution policy is set to the required level?

Comment: "finally works" means, that oneget finally installed the package _somewhere_. tbh, I didn't check where packages were installed. I thought it installed stuff somewhere strange because it displayed packages as installed although I couldn't find or run them. The problem was that it silently failed because of execution policies though - hence the accept mark on this answer.

Comment: I just edited my question title. At the time when I created this question I thought my packages were installed but didn't know where. Therefore, the old question title was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

As mikemaccana [mentions](https://superuser.com/questions/884955/where-do-i-find-my-oneget-windows-package-management-installed-apps#1138346), the install location varies by the provider. Here are the install locations for a few common providers, and also where to find out this information for yourself.

- Chocolatey: `C:\Chocolatey`.
- PowerShellGet: `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`
- Nuget: [Requires you to specify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36081673/712526) the `-Destination`.
- Programs: Currently, [only supports uninstalling](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/wiki/Provider-Requests#package-managers)

### How to find out

You can sometimes glean this information from the results of `Get-Package <name-of-package> | Format-List`. The information is *not* in a standardized format.

```
> (Get-Package vim -providername chocolatey).Source
C:\Chocolatey\lib\vim.8.0.604\vim.8.0.604.nupkg
>  (Get-Package ChocolateyGet -providername PowerShellGet).SwidTagText -split "`n" |`
>> ? { $_ -match "InstalledLocation" }
    InstalledLocation="C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ChocolateyGet\1.0.0.1"
```